# HTML теги в присылаемом письме

Tags: html, ubuntu, email, postfix

Отправляю письмо в Ubuntu 12.04 (postfix) при помощи команды:

```
mail -s "Test" adress@domain.ru < mailbody.html
```

Содержимое mailbody.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" Content="text/html"; Charset=Windows-1251">
        </head>
        <body>
                <b>Заголовок</b>
                Текст письма.
        </body>
</html>
```

Присылаемое письмо:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" Content="text/html"; Charset=Windows-1251"> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
                <b>Заголовок</b> 
                Текст письма. 
        </body>
</html>
```

Почему отображаются теги HTML, вместо форматирования?

Comment: Чтобы отображался форматированный по правилам html текст, письмо должно содержать служебный заголовок, в котором указан mime-тип содержимого (text/html). И это не meta из html. Команда mail на разных системах имеет разные возможности для добавления заголовков. Попробуйте `mail -s "Test" adress@domain.ru -a "Content-type: text/html" < mailbody.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Из комментария пользователя [@Sergey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192547/sergey):*

Чтобы отображался форматированный по правилам HTML текст, письмо должно содержать служебный заголовок, в котором указан mime-тип содержимого (`text/html`). И это не тег `meta` из HTML.

Команда *mail* на разных системах имеет разные возможности для добавления заголовков. Попробуйте `mail -s "Test" adress@domain.ru -a "Content-type: text/html" < mailbody.html`.